# Combinatorial problem about splitting a finite set of real numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Given a finite set $X$ of real numbers greater than one. I'm looking for disjoint sets $A,B$ such that $X=A\cup B$ and such that
$$\prod_{x\in A}x\leq\prod_{x\in B}x\,.$$ 
Especially am I interested of those pair of sets $A,B$ with a maximal product for the elements in $A$, so that the $A$-product is maximal for the set $X$.

This give arise to a combinatorial problem: if $X=\{a,b\},\;a<b$ there is only one possibility. If
$X=\{a,b,c\},\;a<b<c$ there are two maximal possibilities: $ab\leq c\:$ and $\:c\leq ab \:$ since always $a<b<ab<ac<bc$.

In the table below '|' means 'or' and for example 'ab c' stands for:

that $A=\{a,b\}$, $\:B=\{c\}$, that there are different real numbers $a<b<c$ greater than one such that $\:ab\leq c\:$ and such that the partition is a maximal one.

```
a<b                a b
a<b<c              ab c | c ab
a<b<c<d            abc d | bc ad | ac bd | d abc
a<b<c<d<e          abcd e | bcd ae | acd be | abd ce | abc de | ...?
a<b<c<d<e<f        ?
```

How many possible combinations are there for sets with $5,6,\dots,n$ elements?

Hint: it may be more easy to find the impossible combinations 
$\;a_1\cdots a_i\:\:\: b_1\cdots b_j\;$ that doesn't match for any numbers 
$\;a_1,\dots ,a_i,b_1,\dots ,b_j\;$ when substituted.

---

As joriki pointed out there is an equivalent formulation with partitions of sets of real numbers greater than zero such that:
$$\sum_{x\in A}x\leq\sum_{x\in B}x\,.$$

Comment: For the $n=3$ case did you miss the possibility a | bc ? Of course you seem to allow a product of one element, since that showed up in the possibility ab | c. Or maybe a | bc doesn't count since the first product a couldn't be "maximal"... I think what you are counting needs more explanation.

Comment: @coffeemath: the sign | mean 'or' and 'ab c' means $A=\{a,b\},B=\{c\}$...

Comment: @coffeemath: I think the idea is that `a bc` isn't maximal since it's dominated by `b ac`.

Comment: @Lehs: Is it correct to say that you're interested in counting the partitions $X=A\cup B$ of a totally ordered finite set $X$ such that a) your product inequality being satisfied is consistent with the total order (i.e. it cannot be deduced from the total order that the inequality is violated) and b) there is no other partition $X=A'\cup B'$ such that it can be deduced from the total order that $X=A'\cup B'$ satisfies the inequality and the product over $A'$ is greater than the product over $A$?

Comment: In other words you want to count the candidates for the maximal partition, i.e. the partitions for which it cannot be deduced from the total order alone that they are dominated by another partition that satisfies the inequality?

Comment: Note that you can take logarithms to get positive numbers that you want to equipartition as much as possible.

Comment: @joriki: yes, some general cases are possible for some values and some general cases are impossible for all values.

Comment: @joriki: the idea with logarithms seems interesting. I will think about it while sleeping... :)

Comment: I think you're missing `d abc` for $n=4$?

Comment: @joriki: yes, it's possible that $d \leq abc$ is maximal.

Comment: It's a pity you're not clarifying the question based on the comments; this is quite an interesting question, but it's very hard to understand in its current form without reading through the comments.

Comment: @joriki: I will try to do that.

Comment: Please give a more descriptive title to your question.

Comment: `b ac` isn't possible. It's dominated by both `ab c` and `c ab`, and one of those is admissible.

Comment: From a numerical simulation, the number of candidates is $1,2,4,12,24,58,116,260$ for $n=2,\ldots,9$. This sequence isn't in OEIS. The number of admissible partitions (that satisfy the inequality but can't necessarily be maximal) is $2,5,10,22,44,93,186,386$, which is [OEIS sequence A045621](https://oeis.org/A045621) and is given by $2^n-\binom n{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}$. If you're interested, I could explain why this is "the probability that a majority of heads had occurred at some point after $n$ flips of a fair coin", as stated in the comments section of the OEIS sequence.

Comment: @joriki: You're right about ' b ac'. There might be rather intricate relationships that govern the impossibilities, or?

Comment: @joriki: please post an answer about your simulation and about the relationship to A045621!